# Where is the documentation for the built-in JavaScript function toString?

Tags: javascript

I was looking through the jQuery code and found that isArray is implemented using the built-in function toString.  I cannot find the documentation for this function on MDC.  Does the doc exist?  What does this function do?

```
isArray: function( obj ) {
             return toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]";
         },
```

Comment: In converts internal object state to it's string representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was looking through the jQuery code and found that isArray is implemented using the built-in function toString

It's not a builtin. See line 68:

```
toString = Object.prototype.toString,
```

jQuery is taking a copy of the `toString` method on `Object` under its own variable named `toString`. The `Object#toString` method is documented at MDC [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Object/ToString) (and by ECMAScript itself). jQuery then calls the variable copy of the method using `call` and passing in the object as `this`. This roundabout calling method is so that you can't make an object that overrides `toString()` and might return the string `'[object Array]'`.

(In particular, the string `'[object Array]'` itself would have `[object Array]` as its `toString()` value, and so would erroneously be detected as an Array, if the `obj.toString()` were called directly. Calling `Object`'s base implementation of `toString()` avoids this.)

Testing the `toString()` representation is ugly as hell (and still not quite 100% in the case of host objects), but the more straightforward `obj instanceof Array` doesn't work for cross-window-scripting, since `Array` is a different constructor in each window/frame.

ECMAScript Fifth Edition adds the function `Array.isArray(obj)` to avoid this unpleasantness. Browser support is currently poor, however.

Comment: I see.  Your explanation makes it mostly clear.  When I said that toString was built-in I meant that it was implemented natively by the browser because calling Object.prototype.toString.toSource() tells you that it's natively implemented.  The only question left is: why is it that methods of Object are accessible from the global scope?  For example the following returns true in Firebug: toString === Object.prototype.toString

Comment: That's a slightly different issue: because in browsers `window` is what ECMAScript describes as the “global object”, all members of `window` are accessible as global variables. This is why you can call eg. `setTimeout()` directly as well as `window.setTimeout()`. `Window` is a type of `Object`, so it happens that methods of `Object` will also be exposed. It's not guaranteed that `toString===Object.prototype.toString`, though; it is for me in Opera, Safari and Chrome, but not IE or Firefox 3.6. If you say `toString.call(obj)` when `obj` is not a `Window` instance, you'll likely get an error.

Comment: Side-issue: in Firefox, for me, `toString!==window.toString`. This is to do with the arcane and confusing world of the inner vs. the outer window — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725188/why-is-window-not-identical-to-window-self-in-internet-explorer. It doesn't hold for other `window` properties.

Comment: Bobince look closely: In the closure that that `toString` function is called, there is an assignment statement: 
`toString = Object.prototype.toString`

The toString function has the value of the built-in `Object.prototype.toString`.

As a side note, this triggers a bug in Blackberry browser, explained here:
http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/#activation-object-in-blackberry-browser

The problem is avoidable by not naming identifiers with something that conflicts with properties of Object.prototype, e.g. var `_toString = Object.prototype.toString`.

Comment: @Garrett: Yes, that's the first thing I said in my answer! (And yeah, it's really sad that the egregious Blackberry scoping bug *still* isn't fixed.)