# what exactly happens when we write window.open()?

Tags: javascript

when we write

```
window.open(url,target,..)
```

a new window is opened.. Can anyone tell me how this is happening internally

Comment: Can you be more specific? I mean, the answer is: The browser opens a window. And yet, I suspect you want more... :-)

Comment: The same thing happen when you double click on the browser icon but window.open() intialize browser window with passed paramter

Comment: Put debugger before you call window.open. Try debugging

Comment: it means internally in your browser, once the command window.open(url,target,..) is invoked, the browser take care the rest, if you have a knowledge in C Language, you are able to understand how things work internally, cause almost everything come from C. It will work direct with your operating system, there the things happen. Then: Your code call window.open(url,target,..) the browser invoke the operating system to do the job.. It was what I have learned sometime (years) ago..

Comment: @TJ: I am handling the appication were i am given a single instance of browser,In which if external appication calls a new window onclick my application is failling. So was thinking of root cause from which i can redirect any new window to self :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's everything I can think of:

1. The browser decides whether to ignore your `open` request depending on its pop-up settings (most browsers will ignore calls to `open` that aren't in *direct* response to a user event, like a click). Assuming it allows it:
2. The browser creates a new window. It may or may not choose to create that window in a new tab, and it may or may not pay any attention to the dimensions and settings you've requested (if you've requested some).
3. The browser sets the `opener` property of the new window so it points to the `window` object of the window that issued the `open` call.
4. The browser starts loading the desired resource into the new window (if you've supplied a resource to load).
5. The `window.open` call returns a reference to the new `window` object.

Note that the references that the windows have to each other are to the "external" facet of the relevant `window` object, which isn't necessarily the same as the actual window object. (Strange but true; it's for security stuff; more in [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725188/why-is-window-not-identical-to-window-self-in-internet-explorer).) So it may be that although you've opened a window, you don't have access to the contents of that window because it's from a different *origin*.

As to the *internals* of how browsers actually do it, that's entirely up to the browser implementation. For open source browsers like Firefox and Chrome, you can find out by looking at the source...

Comment: thank you :) ..for info but as i mentioned my problem in comments, it may be difficult to handle my scenario from the information you have given :)...

Comment: @asha: I'm not sure I followed your comment about an external application creating new windows in the single browser instance, doesn't sound like something I've had to deal with in the past. Good luck with it,

Answer (score 0):

The browser creates a new window, sets the name, dimensions, position, options etc, and then loads the URL into it. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes..How is all this happening internally?

Comment: That depends on the browser and the platform. For Windows, the browser would call the CreateWindowEx() API function and go from there. But this kind of detail is unavailable since most browsers are closed source..

Comment: Firefox and Chromium (which is almost the same as Chrome) are open source ;)

Comment: Alright, then take a look at the Firefox or Chrome source Asha :)