# Javascript in IE: 'this' keyword refers to window object (?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, explorer

I create a JS object in my code (The module pattern):

```
var Validator = {
    regexEmail: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/,

    settings: {
        error_class: "error-field",
        formValid: true
    },

    init: function (form, default_error_class) {
        self = this;
        alert(self == window);
    },
};
```

When running the "init" function on chrome, I get false for self == window (expected).
But when I try it on IE9 I get true(!). Can you tell me why? I would expect 'this' to capture my custom Validator object and not the window

Comment: that depends on how you call it. Perhaps you pass the function as an event handler?

Comment: Just a more detailed explanation: `self = this` assigns `this` to the global variable `self`. Your code would "work" if `self` wasn't a special global variable. `window.self` refers back to `window` and it appears that in some browsers, this property/global variable was made read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your scope when defining 'self'. Also, use explicit not implicit comparators, i.e. === not ==.

```
var Validator = {
    regexEmail: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/,

    settings: {
        error_class: "error-field",
        formValid: true
    },

    init: function (form, default_error_class) {
        var self = this;
        alert(self === window);
    },
};

Validator.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an immediately executed anonymous constructor function

```
var Validator = new function(){
    this.regexEmail = 
        /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    this.settings = {
        error_class: "error-field",
        formValid: true
    };
    this.init = function (form, default_error_class) {
        console.log(this === window);
    };
    return this;
}();
Validator.init(); //=> false
```

Comment: 'init' could use some 'bind'ing.

Answer (score 0):

use  `alert(self === window);` instead of the equality operator. 
Also you can check the accepted answer here for more details about the 2 operators: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

One more thing: as Genius said, fix your scope:

```
var self=this;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that IE is actually correct in this case.

Because you didn't use `var` when defining `self` it is an implicit global. When you try to set this global `self` it fails, because the global object, which in the browser is `window` already has a `window.self` property, which is a reference to the `window`.

[HTML
Living Standard says](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-window-object):

> The window, frames, and self IDL attributes **must** all return the Window object's browsing context's WindowProxy object.

Which would imply that `window.self` should be immutable.

So, `window.self == window` and it alerts true.

**However** because of historical hacks to remain compatible with some old sites, there is a [bug/feature](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=13403#c0) in WebKit and Gecko that allows you to overwrite it even though you really shouldn't be able to. It [seems (at least in Gecko) to have to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725379/778975) with [split objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Split_object).